# How to set a global style to XAML buttons that have exisiting control templates

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, styles, controls

I'm attempting to create a global style so that the mouse cursor will change to a hand when mouseover on any button in the app. However, my buttons have their own control templates that use the IsMouseOver trigger so my global IsMouseOver trigger isn't working. Is there any way to get around this without having to add the setter for the trigger to every button style?

Here is the global style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And here is a button:

```
<Style x:Key="VideoVolumeButtonBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DefaultColorBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="27"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="31"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" CornerRadius="3" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="2">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <ContentPresenter Name="contentPresenter"  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource FocusedColorBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource FocusedColorBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,-2,0,0" TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledColorBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the [`Style.BasedOn` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx) to base your later `Style`s on your global `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="GlobalStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource GlobalStyle}">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you don't want to name your global `Style`, you can simply base it on this named `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource GlobalStyle}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, BasedOn works, but setting the global style doesn't. I was trying to get away with being lazy and not having to edit every style but it looks like that's the better way to do it.